# Can't load a Bootstrap.css library

Tags: css, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, haml

I have a Ruby application, and here is my setup:

I have this HAML code:

```
  .alert.alert-info
    %p="This is the correct style."
```

The sidebar.css has this:

```
/*
 * THIS IS THE MANIFEST FILE FOR THE LAYOUT: SIDEBAR
 *= require_self
 *= require bootstrap
 *= require bootstrap-responsive
 *= require bootstrap_overrides
 *= require layout/buttons
 *= require sidebar/base
*/
```

The web page renders the text "This is the correct style" but not the styling for it.

Here is the page with the styling documentation:

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#alerts

Any idea what I might be missing or need to set up still?  The css styles are just not rendering.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean "just not rendering"? Are there any errors in the logs?

Comment: isn't `/* */` comments in CSS?

Comment: @AndrewMarshall the styles are not rendering.  The text is rendering.

Comment: @uDaY it is the correct syntax for this case.

Comment: uDaY is right, sidebar.css is not a less file so it will be treated like comments.

Comment: @pguardiario No, if using asset pipeline comments at the top are special regardless of the extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you use LESS or not, by I import Bootstrap like this:

`@import "twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap";`